# How to access multiple HTTP GET actions in same controller?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

Here is my web api controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage SensorData(string id) 
    {
        try
        {
            Responds data = AccessRemote.GetDataFromDevice(id);
            DataResponds dataResponds = data.ReturnDatRequest[0];
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, dataResponds);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, ex.Message);
        }
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetLogs(string GetRecordsById) 
    {
        try
        {
            IQueryable<SensorInfo> data = sensorResultsRepos.Get();
            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, data);
            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Here is my resource angularjs definition:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular.module("sensorManagement").factory("SensorResource",
                                            ["$resource",
                                             SensorResource])
    function SensorResource($resource) {
        return $resource("http://localhost:1234/api/SomeData/:id");      
    }
}());
```

Here is web api route:

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "DefaultApiSensor",
            "api/{controller}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Sensor", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

At some point I need to access to **SensorData** action or to **GetLogs** action using the SensorResource service.

The problem that they are both  HTTP GET and both have one parameter.

How can I make call to  **SensorData** and to **GetLogs** if they in one controller and the have sane http get type?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Attribute Routing to easily solve this problem. See [this link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) for more information regarding this topic.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("sensor/{id}")]
public HttpResponseMessage SensorData(string id) 
{
    try
    {
        Responds data = AccessRemote.GetDataFromDevice(id);
        DataResponds dataResponds = data.ReturnDatRequest[0];
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, dataResponds);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, ex.Message);
    }
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("logs/{GetRecordsById}")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetLogs(string GetRecordsById) 
{
    try
    {
        IQueryable<SensorInfo> data = sensorResultsRepos.Get();
        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, data);
        return response;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```